# How to change Visual Studio Auto Format

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

Is there any way to change Visual Studio Auto formatting options? Like VS by default uses close bracket format for Javascripts.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript

Answer (score 26):

For **Visual Studio 2013**:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript
```

[image]

There you can can change formatting options for JavaScript.

For open brace on new line for function:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> Formatting -> New Lines
```