# VS2010: How to set format on enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, formatting, intellisense

I've downloaded the Productivity Power Tools plug-in for VS2010. I'm using the setting to auto insert the closing brace. However, I can't seem to get the editor to format correctly on enter press. Probably best to show what I'm asking with a code snippet:

```
// I will be using the pipe | to show the carret

// At this point, the closing brace is inserted:
var foo = new Foo{|
// So it becomes this:
var foo = new Foo{|}

// Now pressing enter formats it like this:
var foo = new Foo{
    |
}

// BUT THIS IS HOW I WANT THE FORMATTING TO BE:
var foo = new Foo
{
    |
}

// It is however formatted correctly on semilcolon:
// So this:
var foo = new Foo{
    var bar = 5;|
}
// Becomes this:
var foo = new Foo
{
    var bar = 5;
};|
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388268/how-to-change-visual-studio-auto-format ?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through those settings to no avail. What I need to find is a "format on enter" setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called "Auto Brace Completion"
You can get it via Tools-> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> All Extensions
You can turn it OFF if you don't like the default behaviour, and user VS2010 settings

Comment: I am using the "auto brace completion". If you read through the code snippet above, you'll see what I'm trying to accomplish. I want it to be formatted correctly on enter press.