# Why does autoformat for Javascript continue when disabled? Visual Studio 2013 - node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2013, even with the **Tools \ Options \ Text Editor \ JavaScript \ Formatting** options disabled, it keeps fiddling with the indentation of my JavaScript 
file whenever I enter a brace.

I've tried the solution described in place like this, but it doesn't work:  [How to change Visual Studio Auto Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388268/how-to-change-visual-studio-auto-format)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this, it seems the Node.js add-in installs its own "language" for JavaScript, so you have to disable it under  *Tools \ Options \ Text Editor \ **Node.js** \ Formatting*